# Erro JPA com MySQL 8

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, exceção

Olá,

Após atualizar meu banco de dados, minha aplicação vem apresentando exceptions, do tipo **java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException**.

A classe abaixo, é a que ele reclama, dizendo que não existe quando o hibernate tenta cria-la.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Loja")
public class Loja {

// Omitido para facilitar a leitura

}
```

Este é meu arquivo persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

 <persistence-unit name="persistence_elysium">

   <!-- provedor/implementacao do JPA --> 
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

   <properties>
      <!-- dados da conexao -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/elysium?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="pegasus" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />

       <!--  propriedades do hibernate -->
       <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

      <!--  atualiza o banco, gera as tabelas se for preciso -->
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
   </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Reforçando, que começou esse problema ao migrar para o MySQL 8, nas versões anteriores funciona normalmente (testado com a versão 5.7).

Saliento também, que atualizei o mysql-connector, tentei as versões 8.0.11 e 8.0.12 do jar.

Estou usando Windows 10.

As tabelas são criadas tudo com letras minusculas, mesmo no Table name estar capitalizado.

Quando lança a exception, ele diz: *Tabela 'elysium.loja' não existe.*

Ficarei muito grato a quem me auxiliar a resolver esse problema, pois esta me tirando do sério.. rs.

Obrigado!

Comment: Foi criada a database antes de rodar?
O JPA só cria as tabelas, a database não.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode começar a informar sua entity no arquivo persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="persistence_elysium">

   <!-- provedor/implementacao do JPA --> 
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   <!-- Aqui são listadas todas as entidade -->
   <class>pacote.Loja</class>
...
```

Outra coisa é você verificar se tem algum banco de dados que tem a tabela **loja**. Outro banco de dados que não seja **elysium**.
Se tiver terá que excluir.

Isso resolveu para mim.

Se você não quiser excluir o outro banco de dados, a solução seria trocar o nome dessa tabela de `@Table(name="Loja")` para `@Table(name="store")`

Comment: Olá Victor... Eu fiz o teste, tentando declarar a entity dentro do persistence.xml e não deu certo. Sobre deletar outras databases, vou testar e informo, pois realmente tem sim, uma outra database com a tabela loja criada.

Comment: Você deletou ao outro banco de dados ou a tabela **loja** que pertence ao mesmo?

Comment: Se você não quer excluir o outro banco de dados, a solução seria trocar o nome dessa **entity** de `@Table(name="Loja")` para `@Table(name="store")´, por exemplo. Ou qualquer outro nome diferente de Loja. Editei a minha resposta falando isso.

Comment: Obrigado Antonio! Resolveu mesmo dropando a outra database. infelizmente, não posso alterar o nome, o projeto é grande, tem relacionamentos e tudo mais. Espero que isso seja um bug dessa versão do MySQL, porque não tem cabimento isso.. hehe. Porque data1.nomeDaTabela é diferente de data2.nomeDaTabela.